# How can I do C language program with matrix of strings?

Tags: c, string, file, matrix, vector

I have a problem, I was trying to make a C program taht read a file with 50 lines and 11 columns, the problem is that this file is completely made of strings and I made this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h> 

typedef struct
{
char nome[100];
char dica[10][300];
} PAIS;

void main()
{
int i;
i = 0;

PAIS paises[50];
char nome[30];

FILE *arq;

arq = fopen("Dicas3.txt", "r");

//fscanf(arq,"%s", nome);
//printf("%s", nome);

while(!feof(arq))
{

    fscanf(arq,"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", paises[i].nome, paises[i].dica[0][0], paises[i].dica[1][0], paises[i].dica[2][0], paises[i].dica[3][0], paises[i].dica[4][0], paises[i].dica[5][0], paises[i].dica[6][0], paises[i].dica[7][0], paises[i].dica[8][0], paises[i].dica[9][0]);

    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", paises[i].nome, paises[i].dica[0][0], paises[i].dica[1][0], paises[i].dica[2][0], paises[i].dica[3][0], paises[i].dica[4][0], paises[i].dica[5][0], paises[i].dica[6][0], paises[i].dica[7][0], paises[i].dica[8][0], paises[i].dica[9][0]);
    i++;
}



    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

The program compile, but the program dosn´t work. Please, could someone show me how to do a program that read a matrix 50x11 and print in the window this matrix?

the matrix is in this file (is in portuguese, but this matrix is made os strings):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLhGSHIx69Ycrasgtl4lKyxxKPRlSAv2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *but the program dosn´t work.* What does that mean?

Comment: please provide an example of the file Dicas3.txt.

Comment: What do you get? What do you expect? What do you feed is better explained by giving some examples.

Comment: To read s tring with `fscanf`, you must provide a pointer to the string space. So replace `paises[i].dica[0][0]` with `paises[i].dica[0]`. Same for `printf`.

Comment: `while (!feof` is wrong. `feof` will be true _after_ a read operation failed. You need to know _when_ the read operation fails. Use `while (fscanf(..)>0)`

Comment: You also may want to limit the number of lines and the number of characters per field that will be read. So `while (nLines<50 && fscanf(...` and use format specifiers `"%30s %300s ...`

Comment: Please read about [why `while(!feof(file)) {}` is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Also, always check return value of any scanf function call.

Comment: `void main` is deprecated for decades, please don't use that...

Answer (score 1):

Dont't use `feof()` find out reason for [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

If you know well in advance about `no of lines` and `columns`, since in each line 11 columns/strings are there, read `line by line` from file using `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()`. My suggestion is instead of `local array` use **dynamic array** if you want to make it generic solution..

What `nome`[] contains, not clear ? 
using fscanf() :

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[100];
    char dica[10][300];
} PAIS;
int main()
{
    PAIS paises[50];
    char nome[30];
    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("Dicas3.txt", "r");
    if(arq == 0) {
        printf("file not present:\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int i=0,j=0;
    char ch;
    while(fscanf(arq,"%s",paises[i].dica[j])>0) {
        printf("%s  ",paises[i].dica[j]);
        j++;//column
        if((ch = fgetc(arq))=='\n')//when new lines occures, start reading from next lines, do i++
        {
            i++;//rows or lines 
            printf("\n");//manuaally put the new line or use fputc(ch,stdout)
            fseek(arq, -1, 1);//move one letter back 
            j=0;
        }
        else
            fseek(arq, -1, 1);//move to exact position
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps.